# sklearn: Adding names to feature_importances_/coef_ when using ColumnTransformer and Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on the Kaggl insurance pricing competition (https://www.kaggle.com/floser/french-motor-claims-datasets-fremtpl2freq). The data looks like this:

```
   IDpol    ClaimNb Exposure    Area    VehPower    VehAge  DrivAge BonusMalus  VehBrand    VehGas  Density Region
0   1.0        1        0.10       D           5         0       55        50        B12    Regular 1217    R82
1   3.0        1        0.77       D           5         0       55        50        B12    Regular 1217    R82
2   5.0        1        0.75       B           6         2       52        50        B12    Diesel  54      R22
3   10.0       1        0.09       B           7         0       46        50        B12    Diesel  76      R72
4   11.0       1        0.84       B           7         0       46        50        B12    Diesel  76      R72
```

For preprocessing etc. I am using a Pipeline including a ColumnTransformer:

```
pt_columns = ['BonusMalus', 'RBVAge']
log_columns = ['Density']
kbins_columns = ['VehAge','VehPower', 'DrivAge']
cat_columns = ['Area', 'Region', 'VehBrand', 'VehGas']

X_train['RBVAge'] = 0
X_train.loc[(X_train['VehGas'] == 'Regular') & (X_train['VehBrand'] == 'B12') & (X_train['VehAge'] == 0), 'RBVAge'] = 1

ct = ColumnTransformer([('pt', 'passthrough', pt_columns),
                        ('log', FunctionTransformer(np.log1p, validate=False), log_columns),
                        ('kbins', KBinsDiscretizer(), kbins_columns),
                       ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), cat_columns)])
pipe_poisson_reg = Pipeline([('cf_trans', ct),
                      ('ssc', StandardScaler(with_mean = False)),
                      ('poisson_regressor', PoissonRegressor())])
```

Once the model is fitted I'd like to display the feature importances and names of the features like this:

| name | feature_importances_ |
| --- | --- |
| Area_A | 0.25 |
| Area_B | 0.10 |
| VehAge | 0.30 |
| ... | ... |

The problem I am facing is to get the feature names while using a ColumnTransformer. Especially getting the feature names from the KBinsDiscretizer, which uses OneHot-encoding as well, does not work easily. What I have tried so far is creating a numpy array with the feature names manually, but as I have said I cannot manage to get the feature names from the KBinsDiscretizer and this solution does not seem very elegant.

```
columnNames = np.append(pt_columns, pipe['cftrans'].transformers_[1][1].get_feature_names(cat_columns))
```

Is there a simple (maybe even build in) way to create a DataFrame including both the feature names and feature importances?

Well and since we are already here (this might be a bit off topic):
Is there a simple way to create a custom ColumnTransformer which adds the new column 'RBVAge', which I currently add manually?

Comment: Your last question should probably be its own post.  But I'd look into a `FunctionTransformer`, or a very small custom transformer, that takes in the 3 relevant input columns and returns the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a whole lot easier in the upcoming v1.0 (or you can get the current github code), which includes [PR18444](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/18444), adding a `get_feature_names_out` to `KBinsDiscretizer` as well as `Pipeline` (and others).

If you are stuck on your version of sklearn, you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/6c566da8c99b4908a549aeb659cd4b1124bc2448/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py#L381) that does that to help you patch together the same; it appears to not do very much itself, just calling to the internal `_encoder` object to do the work, and `OneHotEncoder` has had a `get_feature_names` for a while (soon to be replaced by `get_feature_names_out`).

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger. Since I have never worked with github, could you give me a hint on how to install the current github code?

Comment: There are pre-releases now on pypi, so maybe that's the better route; with pip, use the `--pre` flag.